# Rexster for Sparql over Titan + Cassandra

Tags: sparql, titan, rexster

I have been running a Titan graph db over Cassandra cluster. In this I have both blueprint graph and RDF graph. I am using rexster server for querying (gremlin) and visualization purpose with no problem. Now I want to do sparql query using rexster.

I have enabled sparql extension in rexster but when I run a sparql query it complains about underlying graph. Exact error is this.

```
{"message":"the graph to which this extension is applied is not a SailGraph implementation","api":{"description":"execute SPARQL queries against a SAIL graph."....
```

Is there a way to tell rexster that graph stored in Cassandra does have Sail compatible graph?

PS: I have no problem in sparql query using sail apis in my code it just that I want an interface like Rexster for sparql query

Answer (score 0):

Please see discussions here:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/KGENLElQBvw/Ot4VFrKQQHwJ

and here:

[Sparql endpoint for SAIL object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25874497/1831717)

The summary of both discussions boil down to: Use the REST Gremlin Extension or RexPro in Rexster and wrap your `Graph` instance in a [GraphSail](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Sail-Ouplementation) instance and then do your sparql query.